# Google Maps API Run Time Error: Null Pointer Exception

Tags: java, android, xml, google-maps

I am new to Android and I'm following the tutorial for Google Maps API at http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidGoogleMaps/article.html#googlemaps_project

I keep getting this error:

```
04-27 16:58:37.778: E/AndroidRuntime(5968): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-27 16:58:37.778: E/AndroidRuntime(5968): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start   
activity ComponentInfo{com.example.mapsapi/com.example.mapsapi.MainActivity}:  
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

This is my MainActivity.java:

```
package com.example.mapsapi;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
  static final LatLng HAMBURG = new LatLng(53.558, 9.927);
  static final LatLng KIEL = new LatLng(53.551, 9.993);
  private GoogleMap map;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

if(map == null){
map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
        .getMap();
}
if(map!=null)
    map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

Marker hamburg = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(HAMBURG)
    .title("Hamburg"));
Marker kiel = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
    .position(KIEL)
    .title("Kiel")
    .snippet("Kiel is cool")
    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
        .fromResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher)));

// Move the camera instantly to hamburg with a zoom of 15.
map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(HAMBURG, 15));

// Zoom in, animating the camera.
map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(10), 2000, null);
   }

  @Override
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
  }

}
```

This is my activity_main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >
</RelativeLayout>
```

This is my Manifest XML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.mapsapi"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
 <permission
    android:name="com.example.mapsapi.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.example.mapsapi.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"       />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.mapsapi.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>



    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.AIzaSyAVbioYpY53ofxwxU6KSNxn_yZoQ28cFZA"
        android:value="AIzaSyAVbioYpY53ofxwxU6KSNxn_yZoQ28cFZA" />

    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

</application>

</manifest>
```

Does anyone know how to fix this? When I run it on my device, the app says that "Unfortunately, MapsAPI has stopped." Thanks in advance!

Comment: post activity_main.xml

Answer (score 0):

When I was working with google maps API about 4 months ago, I remember having an issue similar to this caused by the `getMap()` method, which doesn't always returns the map.

```
if(map == null){
    map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
}
```

If I recall correctly, the line above doesn't guarantee a reference is going to be returned, but it could also return null.

My advice would be to put the rest of the code inside the logical clause, as the following:

```
if(map!=null) {
    map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    Marker hamburg = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(HAMBURG)
        .title("Hamburg"));
    Marker kiel = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(KIEL)
        .title("Kiel")
        .snippet("Kiel is cool")
        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
        .fromResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher)));

     // Move the camera instantly to hamburg with a zoom of 15.
     map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(HAMBURG, 15));

     // Zoom in, animating the camera.
     map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(10), 2000, null);
}
```

Furthermore, to confirm, you can either add breakpoints or print some `Log`s to determine this part of the code is being executed or not due to the map being `null`.

Answer (score 0):

MapFragment in the example of google is outdated..

instead of using mapFragment use the supportMapFragment

example:

```
map = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
    .getMap();
```

and in XML change the fragment:

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/map"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

change

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.AIzaSyAVbioYpY53ofxwxU6KSNxn_yZoQ28cFZA"
    android:value="AIzaSyAVbioYpY53ofxwxU6KSNxn_yZoQ28cFZA" />
```

to

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
    android:value="AIzaSyAVbioYpY53ofxwxU6KSNxn_yZoQ28cFZA" />
```